# How many ways can we group 8 balls into groups of size 3?

Tags: combinations, multinomial-theorem

We have 8 balls, separating them into groups of size 3, we get 2 groups of size 3 and inevitably a group of size 2:

```
000|000|00
```

I wanna see in how many ways is it possible to do so.

I choose the dividers (the lines) : $ 8-1 \choose 3-1$ $ = $ $ 7 \choose 2 $

But I was thinking, can I calculate the combination of choosing groups of 3 balls out of 8 balls to give me the answer? as followed: $ 8 \choose 3 $$ 8-3 \choose 3 $$ 8-3-3 \choose 2 $ = $ \frac {8!}{3!3!2!}  $

But they are obviously different. 
I'm trying to see if it's the same if I group the balls by choosing them or group them choosing the dividers. they don't give same answer. why?

Comment: $\binom72$ counts a lot more than just the number of separations into two groups of three and one group of two.

Comment: @Arthur yeah i guessed it would...but i had no idea how else it's possible to calculate this using the "choosing dividers" ?

Comment: Well, this touches upon why you get to different results as well, and that is: you need to be very clear on what matters. Are the balls different? Are the groups different? $\binom72$ is the answer of the groups are different, but the balls are not, and the group sizes are not fixed, and you're asking how many ways you can distribute sizes to the groups. $\frac{8!}{3!3!2!}$ is the answer if the groups are fixed at 3-3-2, but they are different, and the balls are different.

Comment: @Arthur  That last comment should be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur alluded to in his comment, the answer depends, on if the balls are considered distinct. There are 40,320 ways to arrange 8 objects, if distinct, but if not, like the 8 pawns in the second rank in chess, your 8 items aren't distinct,there's really only one way that looks distinct. In between we have cases like the home rank in chess, 8 objects, but 3 sets of two that can't be seen as distinct. So, we get only 5040 distinct arrangements being possible. With other rules of the arrangement, we may be restricted to 960 ways to arrange them, giving rise to Fisher random ( aka chess 960). Without knowing if they are all distinct, there's no clear answer.